# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6,) and (3,)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I realise this question has been asked before but the solutions proposed about converting list to numpy array do not solve my problem.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
pop_member                                             scores  \
0           0  [0.18041600508077302, 0.22858464943610304, 0.2...   
1           1  [0.20068084127748528, 0.21373704261775583, 0.3...   
2           2  [0.16593641522899372, 0.38625108196251007, 0.3...   
3           3  [0.166185834331544, 0.33164031068142613, 0.191...   
4           4  [0.18027798511494217, 0.18249255288904706, 0.1...   

                                            timestep  
0  [0.0013907990823846528, 0.18140509483556186, 0...  
1  [0.0013907990823846528, 0.1724678206436131, 0....  
2  [0.0013907990823846528, 0.16461921052581957, 0...  
3  [0.0013907990823846528, 0.15999631524775232, 0...  
4  [-0.25701551548128926, 0.17441802772910156, 0....
```

The scores and timestep columns contain lists. Values for reproducing are as shown:

```
pop member 0
scores: [0.18041601 0.22858465 0.2236205 ]
timestep: [0.0013908  0.18140509 0.20914713 0.17436499 0.1785457  0.18833733]
pop member 1
scores: [0.20068084 0.21373704 0.31533351]
timestep: [0.0013908  0.17246782 0.17146181 0.27099373 0.16979124 0.16125755]
pop member 2
scores: [0.16593642 0.38625108 0.3025389 ]
timestep: [0.0013908  0.16461921 0.16421641 0.14843701 0.17370711 0.17566512]
pop member 3
scores: [0.16618583 0.33164031 0.19115312]
timestep: [0.0013908  0.15999632 0.16095213 0.17207548 0.1702441  0.15623793]
pop member 4
scores: [0.18027799 0.18249255 0.13129566 0.19134298]
timestep: [-0.25701552  0.17441803  0.17666349  0.18146539  0.17697329  0.18239527]
```

I am trying to plot timestep on x axis and scores on y using the following code:

```
# plot scores with timesteps 
c = ['blue', 'olive', 'yellow', 'red', 'purple']
for p in range(len(test)):
    plt.plot('timestep', 'scores', data=test.iloc[p], color=c[p], linewidth=2)
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Timesteps')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.show()
```

I already tried converting the lists into numpy arrays. Doesn't work. Any other suggestions pls?

Comment: please provide the list ``scores`` and ``timestep`` in a way we can copy them and reproduce your problem

Comment: Done, pls see now! Sorry for not giving them earlier.

Comment: the ValueError that you get is justified though, you have 3 elements in ``scores`` and 6 elements in ``timestep``. How do you expect these elements to be paired? for example for the ``pop member 0``: ``(x0, y0)=(0.18041601, 0.0013908)``,  ``(x1, y1) = (0.22858465, 0.18140509)``, ``(x2, y2) = (0.2236205, 0.20914713)`` and what comes next?

Comment: ohh. I see. Thank you for explaining, I'll try to figure it out in the data itself then.

Comment: sure, ask again if you get stuck :) btw, i don't think this is correct: ``plt.plot('timestep', 'scores', data=test.iloc[p], color=c[p], linewidth=2)``. I think you mixed up ``df.plot`` and ``plt.plot``

Comment: Oh, I picked up the code from here though: https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/122-multiple-lines-chart

Comment: oh ok, yes, right, my mistake.